# javac assertion error with javax.transaction-api:1.3

Tags: java, maven, jta, java-module, java-10

Environment:

- JDK: 10
- Maven: 3.5
- Maven compiler plugin: 3.7.0

When my project depends on javax.transaction-api:1.2, it does compile without any error. My module-info.java contains:

```
module my.component {
    requires javax.transaction.api;
    // other required modules ...
}
```

However, when my project depends on javax.transaction-api:1.3, the java compiler yields an assertion error. Note that in that case, my module-info.java contains:

```
module my.component {
    requires java.transaction;
    // other required modules ...
}
```

(since the automatic module name of javax.transaction-api is set to java.transaction in the manifest of the 1.3 version)

The assertion error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:244)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:829)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1506)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:633)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1308)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1139)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1065)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:237)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:52)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:992)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit(Printer.java:136)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:197)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:165)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:183)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:165)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage(JCDiagnostic.java:771)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage(ClientCodeWrapper.java:799)
```

This looks like a conflict between the java.transaction module name used by default in the JRE, and the module name declared in the manifest of the javax.transaction-api:1.3 jar file.

Is there a compiler option to prevent this assertion error from occurring?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you provide a verifiable example?